# helm Ignore pre-install hook failure

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have one pre-install hook which creates a dynamic PVC and looks like this

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: my-dynamic-pv
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/resource-policy": keep
    "helm.sh/hook": "pre-install"
spec:
  storageClassName: {{ .Values.persistence.storageClass }}
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

I want to preserve the same PVC across restarts that's why I have provided `"helm.sh/resource-policy": keep`. I am able to create the PVC with the pre-install hook the very first time I start my service. But the subsequent installs/restarts are failing with error `Error: persistentvolumeclaims "my-dynamic-pv" already exists`.

Is there a way to ignore this failure and continue with the helm installation?

Comment: You shouldn't need to tag this as a hook; `helm upgrade` won't delete objects that haven't changed.  Is there a more specific sequence of `helm` commands that's causing problems, especially without the hook annotations?

Comment: I am actually doing a `helm del` and `helm install` here. and this is causing a problem. As per my use case, I should always purge and start my services.

Comment: Please try to use as mentioned - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49344501/how-can-you-reuse-dynamically-provisioned-persistentvolumes-with-helm-on-gke

Answer (score 6):

Use `--no-hooks` flag to the `helm` command to ignore hooks.

```sh
$ helm install --help | grep "no-hooks"
     
 --no-hooks                     prevent hooks from running during install

$ helm install <NAME> <CHART> --no-hooks
```

Comment: I have explored this option. The problem here is it takes an extra option `--no-hooks` with the `helm install` which is not my intention. I want to use the `helm install` without any additional options to it.

Comment: If you want to ignore something that is supposed to happen, you will definitely need to provide something extra. Period.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `helm lookup` function to check the existence of the pvc before creating it.

```
{{- $mypvc := (lookup "v1" "PersistentVolumeClaim" .Release.Namespace (printf "my- 
dynamic-pv")) }}
{{- if not $mypvc }}
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-dynamic-pv
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/resource-policy": keep
    "helm.sh/hook": "pre-install"
spec:
  storageClassName: {{ .Values.persistence.storageClass }}
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
{{- end -}}
```

More on helm lookup funtion - [Helm template functions](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/)

I'm using helm 3.2.1. You will probably need a near version to use the lookup function.